# How to set up the timesheet template so that, for example, an employee can leave and come back in the same day?

Tags: cognito-forms

The timesheet template is great.

How would I set it up so that an employee can leave and come back in the same day?

For instance, for lunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to subtract a lunch break from the total number of hours:

1. Add two time fields labelled Start Break and End Break to your Time Entries repeating section.
2. Set the expression of the Hours calculation field to the following:

   =(To - From).TotalHours - (EndBreak - StartBreak).TotalHours > 0 and (To - From).TotalHours -(EndBreak - StartBreak).TotalHours  < 24 ? (To - From).TotalHours - (EndBreak - StartBreak).TotalHours : 0

Make sure to replace "EndBreak" and "StartBreak" if your fields have different names.

3. Save your changes. Now, the Total Hours calculation field at the bottom will subtract the employee's break time from their total hours.

Comment: Thank you. Calculations beyond the very simple are not my thing.